# OMNeT++ 4.6 floating point precision issue in release mode

Tags: omnet++

I try to move my OMNet++ project to Windows platform from Linux.

After I moved to Windows, I noticed that floating point is not that precise when running in release mode.

For example, I have a time parameter called GUARD_INTERVAL.

I set it 0.000001, and during the simulate progress.
I see it print as 0.000000999999 in release mode.
But it show as 0.000001 in debug mode.

I thought it wouldn't effect the result of simulation.
But it turn out that it will.

So, is there any way to make release mode get the same precision as debug mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a first guess, you can try removing the hashmark (`#`) and the `-march=native -mtune=native` part from this line in `configure.user`:

```
#CFLAGS_RELEASE='-O3 -march=native -mtune=native -DNDEBUG=1'
```

so it becomes this:

```
CFLAGS_RELEASE='-O3 -DNDEBUG=1'
```

Then rebuilding OMNeT++ from the beginning (starting with `./configure`).

If this does not help, then you can also try lowering `-O3` in this line to `-O2`, then `-O1`, or even `-O0` - every time doing a fresh build.

Comment: Thank you. I will give it a try today.

Comment: Great! So, just to be sure: simply removing `-march=native -mtune=native` (and keeping `-O3`) did not help, neither did moving to `-O2`, only `-O1`?